# SAP ABAP Ecc.6 Associate level Exam Books link required

Tags: abap

Can anyone provide me link or Ebooks of ABAP Ecc.6 or the way to fine them for Associalte Level exam preparation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, before trying to answer the question we have to get some termonology right ...

SAP *ECC* stands for *SAP ERP Central Component*, which can be compared to the old *R/3* SAP **application** system. This is **not** the level where the ABAP language is defined.

ABAP is defined as part of the SAP kernel also know as *SAP BASIS*, which would be version 700 with an ECC 6.0 system.

Anyway, the best in depth book about the ABAP 4GL is probably Horst Keller's [ABAP Objects](http://www.sap-press.com/product.cfm?account=&product=H1934). I believe it's only distributed by [SAP PRESS](http://www.sap-press.com). So if they don't offer it as eBook then there is none. You should also find a great deal of information about ABAP online at [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/ce/b518b6513611d194a50000e8353423/content.htm).

And BTW, I'm not affiliated with sap.com nor sap-press.com. It just happened that I was looking for the best ABAP book myself a while ago.